# Inserindo coluna na tabela banco de dados mysql e após fazendo o update na mesma coluna criada

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update, sql-insert

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema:

1- O "USER" do sistema cadastra um serviço para um determinado cliente que contratou esse serviço.
2- Esse cadastro é feito via um form.php...
3- Envio esses dados diretamente para um SCRIPT.PHP e automaticamente cria uma coluna na tabela cliente dando referência ao serviço que o cliente contratou.
4- Com isso, cada cliente cadastrado terá um ou vários serviços cadastrados no banco na sua tabela cliente.

Vamos lá! O que está acontecendo...
Eu consigo fazer um ALTER TABLE na tabela cliente e consigo criar a coluna do "serviço_contratado"...
Mas não consigo inserir automaticamente o texto referente ao serviço na coluna do "serviço_contratado" para cada cliente...
Segue o código..

```
// DADOS vindo do form
$ID_CLIENTE_ACB = trim($_POST['ID_CLIENTE_ACB']);
$servicos = $_POST['campoServico'];
$servicosAdd = implode($servicos);
// --------------------------------

$servicosAdd = str_replace(" ", "_", $servicosAdd);

//Tirando os acentos dos serviços para criar a COLUNA no BANCO MYSQL
function tirarAcentos($servicosAdd){

    return preg_replace(array("/(á|à|ã|â|ä)/","/(Á|À|Ã|Â|Ä)/","/(é|è|ê|ë)/","/(É|È|Ê|Ë)/","/(í|ì|î|ï)/","/(Í|Ì|Î|Ï)/","/(ó|ò|õ|ô|ö)/","/(Ó|Ò|Õ|Ô|Ö)/","/(ú|ù|û|ü)/","/(Ú|Ù|Û|Ü)/","/(ñ)/","/(Ñ)/"),explode(" ","a A e E i I o O u U n N"),$servicosAdd);
}

$servicosAdd = tirarAcentos($servicosAdd);
$servicosAddM = strtoupper($servicosAdd);

//ALTERAR TABELA BANCO DE DADOS MYSQL()
$alterTableSql = "ALTER TABLE cad_cadastro_cliente_acb ADD SERV_".$servicosAddM." VARCHAR(40)";
$usuario_conect = mysqli_query($connect, $alterTableSql);

//INSERIR SERVIÇO NA TABELA CRIADA
$UpdateSql = "UPDATE cad_cadastro_cliente_acb SET SERV_$servicosAddM= $servicosAdd WHERE ID_CLIENTE_ACB = $ID_CLIENTE_ACB";

$usuario_conect = mysqli_query($connect, $UpdateSql);

echo"<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
alert('Serviço Cadastrado com sucesso!');
window.history.back();
</script>";
die();

mysqli_close ($usuario_conect);
```

Obrigado e preciso de ajuda !!! kkkk

Comment: colocar um script `alter table` num código php? isso é muito estranho, o código já deveria executar com a tabela com o modelo final, esse código não faz sentido. Sobre o update, já viu se o comando na variável `$UpdateSql` está correto?

Comment: Cara, o os serviços são inseridos na tabela do cliente dinamicamente via web... Por isso o update... Você teria alguma sugestão melhor ? Abraços e obrigado

Comment: o ponto não é o update, isso está ok, como coloquei no comentário, verificiou se o valor da variável está ok? agora fazer alter table? isso não se coloca numa página, fora que seu script nem valida se a coluna já não existe, o que claramente vai dar erro uma hora. Sem entender bem o que faz não da pra ajudar ,mas posso te dizer com certeza que esse `alter table` não está bem, poderia fazer um insert com os valores numa tabela qualquer, isso faria mais sentido

Comment: Pq não cria uma tabela para armazenar o serviço e vincula o ID do servico ao cliente?
Caso tenha mais de um serviço use table relacional N:N, que seria uma tabela CLIENTE_SERVICO, mais simples, sem contar que isso ai pode receber um SQL INJECTION

Comment: Maravilha... Pensei nesta opção "Tabela relacional"... Já existe esta tabela de serviços... Vou fazer esta relação cliente = serviços... Obrigado pessoal